# Get request doesn't get executed in swift, getting nil value error where URL is passed in the request

Tags: ios, swift, url, get, request

I am trying to add a GET request in my application.
The values or the final url string is flowing correctly in my sURL variable. But still while executing this code I get "Found nil error" at line - "var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: sUrl)!)"

Please help.

[image: Postman image - that contains 'Params' in it.]

My code -

```
class AllStickerService {
    static let allStickerInstance: AllStickerService = AllStickerService()
    var delegateAllSticker: AllStickerProtocol!
    
    func fetchAllSticker(category: String, APITokenString: String) {
        var sUrl = "http://xyzabc.com/api/stickers"
        let params = ["category": category]
        
        var sParams = ""
           for (key,value) in params {
              sParams += key + "=" + value
            print("\(key), \(value)")
           }
        if !sParams.isEmpty {
            sParams = "?" + sParams
            sUrl = sUrl + sParams
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: sUrl)!)
        print(request)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("Bearer "+APITokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if (response as? HTTPURLResponse) != nil {
                
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                    print(httpResponse)
                }
                
                if let data = data{
                    do {
                        guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else { return }
                        print(json)
                    }catch {
                        print("Error\(error)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't force unwrap and don't use string concatenation use `URLComponents` to create your URL. String concatenation won't percent encode the space in your parameter.

Comment: Enable App Transport?

Comment: The content type header is unnecessary for a GET request too.

Comment: @ElTomato It is already set to 'Yes'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force unwrapping is rarely a good idea.  Either is using string concatenation to create URLs; Aside from potential security problems, you have to worry about things like url encoding, which is your problem here.

Your `category` parameter value has a space, this needs to be encoded as %20, but you don't do this and you end up with an invalid URL string.  You don't see this with Postman because it is encoding the space for you behind the scenes.

A better approach is to use `URLComponents`, `URLQueryItem` and use conditional unwrapping

```
func fetchAllSticker(category: String, APITokenString: String) {
     var sUrl = "http://xyzabc.com/api/stickers"
     let params = URLQueryItem(name:"category", value: category)

     if var urlComponents = URLComponents(string:"http://xyzabc.com/api/stickers") {
         
         urlComponents.queryItems = params
         
         if let url = urlComponents.url {
             var request = URLRequest(url: url) 
             ...
         }
    }
```

I would also recommend you look into using `Decodable` to handle your JSON response rather than `JSONSerialization`

Comment: @Pawlw11 Thank you for input. Your answer worked.